# Magento add fee/charge to payment method if subtotal below amount

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, checkout

I need to add a fee/charge to a payment method, if the subtotal is below 650,-
Is that possible? And how can I do it?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below link and it will help to you for add fee/charge on checkout page.

Link : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

Comment: Thanks. But the guide dont tell any think about, how to do if you want the payment fee to 0,- when you buy for over 650,-